# Nice empty nodes with stable angles in forest

Tags: forest

I'm new to the forest package. Essentially, I am trying to get something that will look like this:

[image]

The branching angles are large and matching for every node, even the empty one, and there are no gaps between the branches. So far, what I have for my tree is this:

```
 \forestset{ xlist/.style={ phantom, for children={no edge,replace by={[,append,
 delay={content/.wrap pgfmath arg={\csname @alph\endcsname{##1}.}{n()+#1}}
 ]}}
 },
 xlist/.default=0
 }

\begin{forest}
 [vP, for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north},
 delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate}{}}
 [DP[\textit{il mare}]]
 [
 [v$_{\textrm{\footnotesize{\sc caus}}}$[\textit{si}]]
 [SC
 [DP[\textit{la casa},tier=word1]]
 [V$_{\textrm{\footnotesize{Adjectival}}}$[\textit{bruciata}, tier=word1]]
 ]
 edge={}]
 ]
\end{forest}
```

which achieves this result:

[image]

thank you everyone for the help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I upvoted your question as it is good, includes code and includes images so thank you! One thing I would improve for your questions in the future (which hopefully there are many and hopefully answers too!) is to make the code you include compile i.e. begin with your `\documentclass{}` and end with `\end{document}`. It is okay in this case as it can be built into one easily by those who know the `forest` package as the missing stuff is easy enough to know, but just a tip for the future in case it is not so simple, hope you enjoy it here!

Answer (score 2):

The `forest` manual provides the `nice empty nodes` style, which is modified slightly in the code below. Note that your `xlist` style is not actually used in your code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
  nice empty nodes/.style={
    for tree={calign=fixed edge angles, calign angle=60},
    delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,
    for current and siblings={anchor=north}}{}}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
 [vP, for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north}, nice empty nodes
 [DP[\textit{il mare}]]
 [
 [v$_{\textrm{\footnotesize{\sc caus}}}$[\textit{si}]]
 [SC
 [DP[\textit{la casa},tier=word1]]
 [V$_{\textrm{\footnotesize{Adjectival}}}$[\textit{bruciata}, tier=word1]]
 ]
 edge={}]
 ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

- For your tree I would use `linguistics` library. Using it the code is much shorter and simple.
- The `for tree` option `if n children=0{font=\itshape}{}` is for text in the italic shape.
- The command `\textsubscript` is for subscript text:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}    % v2.1.5

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree={inner sep=2pt, 
%          anchor=center
           if n children=0{font=\itshape}{},
          }
[vP
    [DP
        [il mare]
    ]
    [, coordinate
        [v\textsubscript{\textsc{caus}}
            [si]
        ]
        [SC
            [DP
                [la casa]
            ]
            [V\textsubscript{Adjectival}
                [bruciata]
            ]
            ]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]